# Logging into GameCenter fails in iOS9 (Unity)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, ios9, game-center

In a Unity project running on iPhones in iOS 9 I'm calling:
Social.localUser.Authenticate(ProcessAuthentication);

On a phone with all data cleared, this brings up Apple's dialogue to log into GameCenter. I enter an email address and password from an existing GameCenter test account. The dialogue seems to lock up for a few seconds. It then returns to the game, passing false (failure) to ProcessAuthentication.

When I try logging into the same account via the GameCenter settings menu, it brings up a Terms and Conditions screen that I wasn't getting in-game - I suspect that it's failing to bring it up and acting as though you refused to accept. If I complete the login process in settings I can run the game and GameCenter works fine.

This problem didn't occur in iOS 8.

Is this normal? Does anyone know if it can be fixed?

Edit:
Output message being printed:

Setting up 1 worker threads for Enlighten.
Thread->id: 40933000 -> priority: 1

2015-10-29 16:02:02:02.287 autowarriors[365:26287] plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterAuthenticateExension interrupted

2015-10-29 16:02:02:02.288 autowarriors[365:26233] plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterAuthenticateExension invalidated

2015-10-29 16:02:02:02.308 autowarriors[365:26220] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo=(Message=Service Connection Interrupted)
Failed to authenticate

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 64)

-> applicationWillResignActive()

Comment: This appears to be because our game is fixed to landscape view and GameCenter Terms&Conditions can't handle that on smaller devices.